# How can I set an animated background image or lock screen?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, customization, animations

I have this gif:

[image: cool spaceships flying gif]

I wish to set it as my lock screen image, but I am unable to do so because if I go into **Settings > Background**, and then go to the **Pictures** tab, I am only able to see still images in the `Pictures` folder, even though my gif is in there. As is made clear in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1489116), they are not going to fix that.

So I am still wondering how to set this gif as a lock screen image, or convert this gif into something that can be used that way. How can I do this? Is there any way to convert a gif into many still image files and then some how automatically edit that XML configuration file to make the animation work and show on the lock screen?

Ubuntu 15.04 GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like https://launchpad.net/livewallpaper , but you can't add your own video's /GIF's.

With this one you can: https://www.ostechnix.com/set-animated-video-wallpapers-linux-desktop/

I haven't used them, so you should make a back-up of your system before installing the new software.

And on a sidenote: you should upgrade Ubuntu 15.04 to a newer LTS version, 15.04 isn't a LTS version and support ended approx. 9 months after the release (march 2016). 16.04 and 18.04 are both newer LTS versions.